# After setting up Tailwind in Angular, global scss variable imports no longer works

Tags: angular, postcss-loader

My objective is to configure Tailwind in an existing Angular project, with Material and scss. I have followed this [guide](https://dev.to/seankerwin/angular-8-tailwind-css-guide-3m45), and most things seem to work. However in the project we have a `variables.scss` file, with multiple variables defined like:

```
$spaceSize32: 32px;
$spaceSize58: 48px;
```

We import the variables in our component style with:

```
@import 'variables.scss';
```

However, after upgrading to tailwind, it throws the following error when we try to compile Angular:

```
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/postcss-loader/src/index.js):
Error: Failed to find '~variables.scss'
```

What can we do to fix this error?

Comment: Variables.scss file is your project file or the Tailwind.

Comment: the tilde (~) appears to not be supported by postcss (https://github.com/postcss/postcss-import/issues/403)

Comment: variables.scss is a project file

Comment: I think you should define your variables.scss file path while importing.For example @import ‘./variables.scss’

Comment: Ended up removing the global variables 